# Error-labels of q-field (in combination with q-input) when using Quasar Framework

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, quasar-framework

I have two questions regarding [error-labels](http://quasar-framework.org/components/field.html) of q-field (in combination with q-input) when using [Quasar Framework](http://quasar-framework.org/):

1. When the error-label shows it moves the button below it further
   down. How can I solve this?
2. When used in combination with vuelidate (as recommended for
   validation) I would like to show the applicable validation error(s).
   So instead of just showing:   `error-label="Please type a valid name"` I would like to show the (multiple) actual validation errors vuelidate
   finds, so e.g. more in line with: "Name must be longer then 4
   characters and no numericals". How would I do that using the
   `error-label` quasar provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try `<q-component :content-css="{minWidth: '80vw', minHeight:
   '80vh'}">` (you should set a minimum width and/or height to avoid
   this behavior)

   2. Check this: http://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/2263/dynamic-error-message/4